# jade form does not seem to post

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Folks,
  The following code does not seem to have the form submitting properly.  Please correct

```
block main
    .container
        form.form-signin(name='signin', action='/auth' method='post')
            h2.form-signin-heading Please sign in
            input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Email address', autofocus='autofocus', id='username')
            input.form-control(type='password', placeholder='Password', id='password')
            label.checkbox
                input(type='checkbox', value='remember-me')
                | Remember me
            button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(type='submit') Sign in
                &nbsp;
```

Comment: Missing comma after `action='/auth'` on line 3

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, was not creating

```
.container
        form.form-signin(action='/auth' method='post')
            h2.form-signin-heading Please sign in
            input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Email address', autofocus='autofocus', name='username')
            input.form-control(type='password', placeholder='Password', name='password')
            label.checkbox
                input(type='checkbox', value='remember-me')
                | Remember me
            button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(type='submit',name='submit') Sign in
                &nbsp;
```

Comment: Missing comma after `action='/auth'` on line 2